# Having trouble getting data from the Facebook graph api

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working on a wedding website for my mom and her fiance and I have been trying to access her Facebook photo albums and have the images she upload show up on their website. I have created an app and I also have an extended access token. The problem I am having is when I try to do a get request using jQuery getJSON; I'm getting an error message that says

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "An active access token must be 
    used to query information  about the current user.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 2500,
   "fbtrace_id": "GPNGyX+1rmR"
}
```

}

Where I'm getting confused is I have an active access token and I also extended it so that it wouldn't end the same day and I still get this message. This is what I am putting in the url

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name?access_token=EAAPSZBJrjdT8BAAOz6lLTxw5albUCEzCZCRI17MO1x5Cw4vhnu7LTW4sogBSxLRwCNIqWall3wkqVoYkqAuvToX0xupWzHNimc3ZBqFCXTUVPcDF5HOl5vtSLS0btnAoVYh90kNBHEBZCOG3j0s4cnCnbl6QvUkZD

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you really should not post access tokens anywhere, always keep them secret...

Comment: ...especially when it´s one with the ability to post to all your pages. editing the question will not work, you should refresh the app secret in your app settings asap.

Comment: will do, I appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the correct format: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name&access_token=xxx

You had two questionmarks in the URL.

Comment: If I wanted to show all the images in an album using jquery each function also using this query https://graph.facebook.com/102060453138941?fields=photos{picture}&access_token=xxx how do I go about setting up the   each function. Right now I have this inside the each function <img class="" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ this.data +'/picture" />

Comment: why not just use vanilla js instead of jquery? a simple for loop would do it. not sure what you want to achieve though, you should create a new question for this as it´s not directly related to this one.